# NSBundleResourceRequest beginAccessingResources never completes

Tags: ios, swift, on-demand-resources

I am trying to utilize ODR in my application, but the `beginAccessingResources` never completes. Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
let bundleResourceRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: tags)

bundleResourceRequest.beginAccessingResources { error in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error {
            bundleResourceRequest.endAccessingResources()

            // Handle error

        } else {
            // Successful
        }
    }
}
```

I have started simple by tagging a `.sks` file with the tag `Level1` and another `.sks` with the tag `Home`. When I begin access resources for the tag `Home`, I get a successful completion with no problem. However, when I try with the `Level1` tag, the completion block never fires. I don't receive an error or success. When I look in Disk Report, it shows `Home` is `In Use` and `Level1` is `Downloading` with a progress bar that never moves. `Level1` is a total of 16 KB so it isn't too large, and I have let it sit for ~10 minutes with no success.

What could be causing this function to never complete?

Comment: I have the same problem now. What did you do to resolve that issue? You changed `Embed Asset Packs in Product Bundle` to Yes for `Debug`. Is it correctly working in Production or not?

Comment: My problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63415239/why-my-on-demans-resource-is-still-in-downloading-status).

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this by going to Build Settings and changing `Embed Asset Packs in Product Bundle` to `Yes` for Debug.